# Associate each enum member to a class and get generic info from that class

Tags: c++, enums

Suppose I have lots of audio effects into an enum:

```
enum AudioEffect {
    CHORUS,
    FILTER,
    GAIN,
    OSCILATOR,
    PHASER
};
```

and for each one, there's a class that specifies how the audio bytes will be processed:

```
class ChorusProcessor  : public ProcessorBase
{
public:
    ChorusProcessor()
    {
    }
}

class FilterProcessor  : public ProcessorBase
{
public:
    FilterProcessor()
    {
    }
}
```

Each of these processor classes will have parameters that can be changed, these are the audio controllers (mute/unmute, sliders, etc).

Without making an instance of the processors, is it possible to traverse the enum, and for each enum, get the list of controllable values with its min and max values?

I think C++ is smart enough to let us do these things. I'd begin thinking on how to associate `Chorus` with `ChorusProcessor`, `Filter` with `FilterProcessor` etc. How would I do that?

Then I'd make all the processor classes derive from a class like `AudioEffectDescription` which has some `constexpr`s that describe each parameter.

Comment: Pretty gnarly, but maybe something like [this](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/bxq7Eo4K3)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with a bit of trickery but I am not sure how useful it really is.
The main problem you will have to face it that generally you **can't iterate easily through all values of an `enum`**. As the underlying data type for a normal `enum` is integer starting you might use [a simple loop for a plain `enum`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/261986/9938686) but this fails for any `enum` where values are set manually such as

```
enum class AudioEffect {
  Chorus = 3,
  Filter = 6,
  Gain = 5,
  Oscillator = 2,
  Phaser = 1
};
```

Generally you will have to create an additional data structure like a `std::tuple` or a `std::vector<AudioEffect>`, add all the possible values and loop over using something like a variadic template (As soon as you use template parameters a normal loop won't suffice anymore). Furthermore in C++ there is **no such thing as `virtual static` functions**.

---

**Specialised template class**

The best I can come up with is:

- Declare a class `template <AudioEffect E> class Processor` and **specialise** it for all possible **template parameters**. I added two `static constexpr` functions for getting the `min` and the `max`. These will have to be declared in all specialisations. I have used two functions `min` and `max` that return a minimum and a maximum value but you could return a `std::string_view` (or in C++20 you will be able to return a `constexpr std::string`) that contains more information about the different limits.

  ```
  template <AudioEffect E>
  class Processor: ProcessorBase {
  };

  template <>
  class Processor<AudioEffect::Chorus>: ProcessorBase {
    public:
      // Or a single function for printing all the settings of this class
      static constexpr int min() {
        return 1;
      }
      static constexpr int max() {
        return 99;
      }
  };
  ```
- Then I can **print** all the limits with a **variadic template function** and **C++17 fold expressions** (assuming here that each instance of the `template class Preprocessor` has a `static constexpr` function `min` and another one `max`

  ```
  template <AudioEffect... E>
  std::string print() {
    std::stringstream ss;
    ((ss << E << "\t min: " << Processor<E>::min() << ",\t max: " << Processor<E>::max() << std::endl), ...);
    return ss.str();
  }
  ```
- This print function can be called inside the main listing all possible parameters

  ```
  std::cout << print<AudioEffect::Chorus,AudioEffect::Filter,AudioEffect::Gain,AudioEffect::Oscillator,AudioEffect::Phaser>() << std::endl;
  ```

[Try it here!](https://wandbox.org/permlink/OTZLKn9rNQE7bBZC)

---

**Map**

Another similar way would be to map the `enum` to the `class`es (that do not have to be specialised templates anymore) with `traits` like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41415384/9938686) by

- Defining your classes like

  ```
  class ChorusProcessor: ProcessorBase {
    public:
      static constexpr int min() {
        return 1;
      }
      static constexpr int max() {
        return 99;
      }
  };
  ```
- Then **specialising a `template struct Map`** that maps in between the `enum` values and the `class`es

  ```
  template<AudioEffect> struct Map;

  template<> struct Map<AudioEffect::Chorus> {
    using type = ChorusProcessor;
  };
  ```
- And introducting a print function again with variadic templates like

  ```
  template <AudioEffect... E>
  std::string print() {
    std::stringstream ss;
    ((ss << E << "\t min: " << Map<E>::type::min() << ",\t max: " << Map<E>::type::max() << std::endl), ...);
    return ss.str();
  }
  ```

[Try it here!](https://wandbox.org/permlink/uphhfvzWwWYH6BZN)

This is pretty similar to the [solution proposed in the comments](https://wandbox.org/permlink/NQa1DOYuXCVebWW8) that makes use of an `std::tuple`

```
using Processors = std::tuple<
  ChorusProcessor,
  FilterProcessor,
  GainProcessor,
  OscilatorProcessor,
  PhaserProcessor
>;

std::tuple_element_t<AudioEffect::Filter, Processors>::value
```

---

**Brief but dirty**

If you use an `enum` without specifying values explicitly you could also go away with a dirty solution only supplying the first and the last value of the `enum` (C++17)

```
template <AudioEffect Begin, AudioEffect End>
std::string print() {
  std::stringstream ss;
  ss << Begin << "\t min: " << Processor<Begin>::min() << ",\t max: " << Processor<Begin>::max() << std::endl;
  if constexpr (Begin != End) {
    ss << print<static_cast<AudioEffect>(static_cast<int>(Begin)+1), End>();
  }
  return ss.str();
}
```

This way you could simply call it with the **first and the last value of the `enum`**

```
std::cout << print<AudioEffect::Chorus,AudioEffect::Phaser>() << std::endl;
```

[Try it here!](https://wandbox.org/permlink/O1W9CFPOO2XzmxUs)

---

**Enum reflection**

Finally with the GCC, Clang and MSVC compiler there is a **hacky way** to get some enum properties with the **`__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` identifier** which is described [here](https://taylorconor.com/blog/enum-reflection/). (There are a few typos in the original code and it is not `constexpr` so better try it [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/j60oBhS5OCLkprZr).)
With it you could completely get rid of the `Begin` and `End` by **looping from `0` to the detected number of `enum` values**. This is a bit more complicated so I will just leave the code [here for you to try](https://wandbox.org/permlink/dVboYA9035TYv4aQ). With it you can output all classes without specifying all the `enum` values explicitly:

```
std::cout << print<AudioEffect>() << std::endl;
```