# Is There any Way to associate a Value to a Type?

Tags: c++, templates, struct, template-meta-programming

So I've written a basic type tagging structure:

```
struct TypeTag
{
    inline static size_t counter = 0;

    template<typename T>
    static size_t get()
    {
        static size_t value = counter++;
        return value;
    }
};

class c1 {};
class c2 {};
class c3 {};
class c4 {};

int main()
{
    std::cout << "c1: " << TypeTag::get<c1>() << '\n';
    std::cout << "c2: " << TypeTag::get<c2>() << '\n';
    std::cout << "c3: " << TypeTag::get<c3>() << '\n';
    std::cout << "c4: " << TypeTag::get<c4>() << '\n';

    std::cout << "\n================================\n\n";

    std::cout << "c1: " << TypeTag::get<c1>() << '\n';
    std::cout << "c2: " << TypeTag::get<c2>() << '\n';
    std::cout << "c3: " << TypeTag::get<c3>() << '\n';
    std::cout << "c4: " << TypeTag::get<c4>() << '\n';
    
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
c1: 0
c2: 1
c3: 2
c4: 3

================================

c1: 0
c2: 1
c3: 2
c4: 3
```

This will associate a type to a value.

Here's a working example of it: https://godbolt.org/z/9rqK6Pasz

Suppose we know the value at compile time: `template <size_t value>`; is there any way to do the opposite? Is there any way to associate a variable value to a type?

```
template <size_t value>
struct TypeFrom
{
    using type = ... // SOMETHING HERE 
};
```

Comment: I am not sure I follow. You have not exactly mentioned the purpose of the template.

Comment: for template<typename T> static size_t get()?

Comment: Yes, that is the one I am referring to. Because you haven't used `T` in your program.

Comment: Each T will have its own get() method <=> unique static size_t value for each T

Comment: You mean [like this](https://godbolt.org/z/3foa7Yzo3)?

Comment: I've edited the question to include an example of its usage

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67627762/22081063) do what you're looking for? Maybe you could adapt it to your use.

Comment: @Brian61354270 essentialy, but with less manual work

Comment: well you could do `using type = Types<value>` where you earlier define `Types` as a template typedef with specializations for c1, c2, c3, c4 etc.

Comment: _" Suppose we know the value at compile time; is there any way to do the opposite? Is there any way to associate a variable value to a type?"_ - Soppose we know what your asking about?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Sorry for not being clear enough, i was refering to the `template <size_t value>`. I've edited the question.

Comment: It's never to late to upgrade the question

Comment: Request it in your Last Will and Testament if you have to ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As shown, this is not possible for some fairly fundamental reasons: C++ simply does not work this way.

The value of `TypeTag::get<T>` is known only at ***runtime***. The value for a given `T` depends on the order of the first call to a template instance for this particular `T` relative to first calls for other types. It's entirely possible that each time the program runs the same types get different `TypeTag`s. This is fundamental to C++: a `static`ally-scoped object is constructed the ***first*** time its scope gets entered. The fact that the scope is generated from a template is immaterial. Effectively `counter++` gets evaluated, to initialize the `static size_t value` ***the first time*** its `get()` gets called.

So, when all is said and done, a particular `TypeTag::get<T>` value is known only at ***runtime***.

But templates parameters (such as the `size_t n` in `ValueType<n>`) must be known at ***compile time***. This is fundamental to C++. The End.

Comment: But if we now know the value from `template <size_t value>` at compile time; is it still not possible?

Comment: If `T` is `int`, for example, you don't know what it's `value` is 2, for example, at compile time. Because the next time you run this program it can be 4. Or 42. So, how do you believe you can figure out what type `2`, or `4`, or `42` is, at compile time, when the actual types that correspond to those values will only be known at runtime?

Comment: @bibanac If you really know the value **and the complete set of possible types** at compile time, instead of adding the types dynamically at runtime as shown in your code, then you can just use `std::variant_alternative_t` or `std::tuple_element_t`, no need to write your class. Otherwise, it is impossble, as this answer correctly indicates.